# Invertible operator such that its characteristic and minimal polynomials coincide

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, minimal-polynomials, principal-ideal-domains

Let $T \in GL(V) \subset End(V)$, where $V$ is finitely dimensional vector space over field. Suppose the minimal polynomial $\mathcal{m}_T$  and it's characteristic polynomial $\chi_T$ coincide. What can we say about $\mathcal{m}_{T^{-1}}$?

The only thing I can come up with is that $V \cong \mathbb{K}[x]/( \mathcal{m}_T)$ as  a $\mathbb{K}[x]$ -module  so it has a basis in which the matrix is not that bad. But I really don't want to find the inverse matrix and hope there is a more clever way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $\ m_T\ $ and $\ m_{T^{-1}}\ $ are both monic, $\ \deg m_T=n\ $, $\ \deg m_{T^{-1}}=r\ $, and
$$
m_T(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k\ .
$$
Then multiplying the equation
$$
T^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k T^k=0
$$
by $\ T^{-n}\ $ gives 
$$
a_n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k \left(T^{-1}\right)^{n-k}=0\ ,
$$
so $\ m_{T^{-1}}(x)\ $ must divide $\ x^nm_T\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ $. Conversely $\ m_T(x)\ $ must also divide $\ x^rm_{T^{-1}} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ $.  It follows that $\ r=n\ $ , and $\ m_{T^{-1}}(x)=$$a_0^{-1} x^n m_T\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ $.